# Cake ACLs with Groups and Users added to Projects

Tags: acl, cakephp-2.1

I'm currently working on a platform which is planned to coordinate the communication with customers in future. Users can be added to projects and have certain rights. Therefore users are assigned to different user roles (admin/manager/member/viewer). Admins can view all projects and are allowed to add other users to a project. If a user (e.g. role:member) is added to a project, he will have certain rights (depending on the role), if not, he is not allowed to access the project at all.

I'm using Cake's ACL Component and everything is working great, when i disregard if a user is added to a project or not. The only solution I can think of, is not to grant rights on the group-level, but on the user-level when an admin adds an user to the project.

Is there an easier way to solve this issue? Otherwise I'm afraid that the code would become totally confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a another way (I don't really know if easier, depends on your point of view). The ACL component only helps you to create roles, but you need a role and project-access management, right?

What I do in this cases:

1. Create a Project_Permission table in your database (give it a better name, I'm lacking imagination). Depending on your project, create the associations: a user can be related to many projects and a project can have many users accesing it. If you are following the cake conventions (and your tables are named users and projects) and it doesn't interfere with what you already have, the table should be

   ```
   PROJECTS_USERS
   id
   project_id
   user_id
   created and modified  //if you want to
   ```
2. Create appropriate actions where the admin (or other type if users, that's up to you)
   can add users to projects and save that many-to-many association in
   the previously created table.
3. Since the authorization for the project does not come from the ACL component, you have to create an "authorization" function yourself. I recommend putting this in the beforeFilter() function of the AppController (if you don't have an AppController, you'll have to do it in every controller you want this to work). In this function, check if the logged user is in the existing table and has an association with the project. Something like:

   ```
   function beforeFilter() {
       //let's assume you have the project id somewhere, in a global variable like $this->_projectID
       $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
       $project = $this->Project->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$this->_projectID, 'User.id'=>$user)
       if (count($project) > 0) {
           //the user has permission to see the project
       } else {
           //he doesn't
       }
   }
   ```

It's difficult to give an actual code because I'm not sure of your model associations nor where do you want the code or if you have the variables needed for this available everywhere, but I hope you get the idea. After that it's just a matter of how you want to handle the restriction of access (normally a flash message and redirection is involved).

I hope this is clear enough :S